# Inserting Bootstrap into an external container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue where we use bootstrap our product, but it gets added to clients sites with their CSS, javascript, etc.. What I'm trying to do is set bootstrap to use the width of the content container as the page width.

Part of what I did was set the `width: inherit;` which did help, but I didn't know if anyone has a better solution.

To recap, external site -> div.container -> Our Stuff + bootstrap
Use div.container as page width.

Thanks folks.

Comment: Are you asking if you can make it so that the media queries in Bootstrap respond to the width of div.container instead of the width of the page itself?

Comment: I know that the media queries can't respond to the div.container, but for simplicity sake that would be correct in having the width of the div.container act as the window width for the media queries in bootstrap.

Comment: You'll have to use JavaScript for that. If you want to keep it as pure CSS, you're gonna need to use % values for widths and heights. That's all I can tell you based on the information you've posted here.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. CSS width: inherit; seems to do the trick, but I didn't know if there was another way of making it work better.

Comment: you can't use a full css framework like bootstrap on another page if all you are doing is inserting a widget. Your css needs to be extremely insulated from any other and thus very very specific. Bootstrap has far too much top level style settings in it

Comment: That's what I figured, but was trying to avoid using an iFrame.